# FFMpeg sync timecode with smpte ltc timecode audio signal

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture video from a capture card and I'm extracting 30 jpeg per second.

I will have multiple computer capturing multiple cameras. I want to sync all those camera with a smpte ltc timecode audio signal pass in the audio line in of the camera.

What would be the best way to set the timecode with that audio timecode using ffmpeg?

Here is the command I have which is sync with the timestamp, but sometime some cameras are out of sync because of the clock of the computer:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -f dshow -rtbufsize 1500M -video_size 1920x1080 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -copyts -r 30 -i video="QP0203 PCI, Analog 01 Capture" -r 30 -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vsync 0 -vframes 1800 name%d.jpeg -c copy -vsync 0 -vframes 1800 -f mkvtimestamp_v2 file.txt
```

Comment: Did you check the machine performance when `out of sync` occurs? Usually on my line of work with HD cameras stream processing, each machine (we use HP DL380) process 4 cameras.

Comment: You need to synchronise all the computers using PTP to a Grandmaster clock, and then sync the capture process / timecode against that clock.